# Why does this if condition not work when I add parentheses around the left hand side of the inequation?

Tags: c, if-statement

I was trying out a problem, and my code failed one of its test cases. I traced back the error, and it can be summarized by the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int a = 90000;
  int b = 80000;

  if (a * b <= a + b)
  {
    printf("YES\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("NO\n");
  }
}
```

I would expect the output to be a "NO" (since 90000 * 80000 > 90000 + 80000). But turns out, when compiled and run, the above program outputs "YES".

I suspect this has something to do with the range of an `int` in C. The range of an `int` on a 64-bit OS (the one I have) is 4 bytes, thus all the integers from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 can be represented by an `int`. But `a * b` in the above code is 7200000000, which is well beyond the bounds of an `int`. So I tried casting the value of `a * b` to a `long long int` as follows

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int a = 90000;
  int b = 80000;

  if ((long long int) a * b <= a + b)
  {
    printf("YES\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("NO\n");
  }
}
```

<s>But still the output stays the same, "YES". I can't seem to figure out how I can make the program return the correct output. How can I do it?</s> This has been solved. The above code works perfectly fine.

---

Like MathewHD pointer out in the comments that declaring a and b as `long`s rather than `int`s solves the issue. <s>Then why does casting not work?</s> Casting works (refer the above code). Also, where is this temporary variable having the value of `a * b` stored, and how can I change the data type of that temporary variable?

---

Turns out I was using a slightly different code when the error was generated. Using the above code (the one which includes casting to a long), does give the expected output, however adding parentheses around the left hand side of the condition, makes the program return the wrong output i.e. "YES". The code follows

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int a = 90000;
  int b = 80000;

  if ((long long int) (a * b) <= a + b)
  {
    printf("YES\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("NO\n");
  }
}
```

The main reason why I initially thought of adding the parentheses around the left hand side of the inequation, was to ensure that the compiler does not misinterpret the casting to be for only one of the involved integers rather than their product. So I just wanted their product to be casted. I would love an explanation as to why adding the parentheses does more harm than good, i.e. why doe it make the program return wrong outputs?

One of my previous question also remains: Where is this temporary variable having the value of `a * b` stored, and how can I change the data type of that temporary variable?

Comment: Make the two ints a and b long long ints instead of casting them after you already checked them.

Comment: @MathewHD That works, thank you. But is there any reason why the casting doesn't? Moreover, where is the temporary value of `a * b` stored and how can I change the type of that temporary variable?

Comment: Are you sure this is your actual code? Most compilers won't even check the condition (e.g. [this](https://godbolt.org/z/3beohc)).

Comment: Casting `a` to a `long long int` worked for me, so I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: @MathewHD: casting any operand to `(long long)` will promote the other operand too. The only way I can see this failing would be if `int` was 16-bit on OP's machine, and the initial assignment got screwed up, making both numbers negative. But even that isn't happening, since `(int16_t)90000` is positive.

Comment: @Groo Yes, this is my actual code.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Compiling and running the second code outputs `NO`.

Comment: No, it is not your actual code or you're confusing details. 2nd prints `NO` when compiled on 32-bit machine too.

Comment: I cannot understand how, but the code does run and output "NO" as its output. I swear it output "YES" for the same program (AFAIR) just a few minutes ago. I am sorry for the let down. Thank you for your help. Should I delete this question, or let it be?

Comment: @FakeMod: just cast a close vote and you're done. :D

Comment: What OS and compiler are you using, and what version of each?

Comment: I have updated my question, turned out I copied a slightly different version of the code. The new code does not run as intended. I request you to explain why it happens so.

Comment: I tried out the last code on both gcc and clang. I also tried it on Ubuntu as well as Windows 10.

Comment: *But a * b in the above code is 7200000000, which is well beyond the bounds of an int*  Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thank you for your response. But that issue has been solved by casting the `int`s as `long`s. My problem is that why does adding parentheses make the program behave differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
if ((long long int) (a * b) <= a + b)
```

Because you're casting the *result* of the multiplication, *after* any overflow occurs.  Since both `a` and `b` have type `int`, the result also has type `int` and overflows so the cast doesn't matter.

This works:

```
if ((long long int) a * b <= a + b)
```

Because it converts one of the operands of the `*` operator to a larger type, resulting in the other operand getting converted to match, so the result has type `long long int`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Now it makes complete sense. Thank you.